# ToTable() doesn't return distinct records?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am using datatable to return me distinct records but somehow its not returning me distinct records
I tried like

```
dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Id");
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(row["Id"]);

            }
```

It still returns me all the records. What could be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

My sql is as below

```
   select  t.Update ,t.id as Id, t.name ,t.toDate,t.Age from  tableA  t  Where t.Id = 55 
   union
   select  t.Update ,t.id as Id, t.name ,t.toDate,t.Age  from tableB t  Where t.Id = 55
   order by Id
```

Its very hard to do distinct in my query as there are many columns than mentioned here.

Comment: Can you show us your SQL command please? : )

Comment: the sql that populates the datatable would be really useful as this doesn't show us anything related to getting distinct records

Comment: If you use a database it would be better to use sql to return only distinct records(e.g. by using `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` or a window function). If you want to filter the table in memory you could also use `Linq`: `dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("Id")).Select(g=>g.First()).CopyToDataTable();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you post your comment in answer section so i can look into it

Comment: @Tanner: Go look at what `ToTable` does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx

Comment: Your SQL query makes no sense. You are selecting the same record with the same ID twice.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i have check on date condition in my actual sql. I guess i forgot to post it. Will modify it. Thanks otherwise this query looks nonsense

Comment: @TimSchmelter Also i am selecting in 2 different tables with same. Doesnt it still make sense to you?

Comment: @Happy: i haven't seen that you are selecting from two different tables. We need more informations if we should show you the sql approach to avoid duplicates. You could post another question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no need for seperate question. Your answer has provided solution to me. I guess you are confused because i added Update to my question when someone demanded to post sql query.

Comment: @Happy: Yes and no, it would also be interesting and more efficient to avoid these duplicates in the first place. But if you are happy ... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a database it would be better to use sql to return only distinct records(e.g. by using `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` or a window function).

If you want to filter the table in memory you could also use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("Id")) // assuming that the type is `int`
    .Select(g=>g.First())           // take the first row of each group arbitrarily 
    .CopyToData‌​Table();
```

Note that the power of Linq starts when you want to filter these rows or if you don't want to take the first row of each id-group arbitrarily but for example the last row(acc. to a `DateTime` field). Maybe you also want to order the groups or just return the first ten. No problem, just use `OrderBy` and `Take`.

Comment: I am not getting option of AsEnumerable

Comment: @Happy: What framework are you using? You have to use at least .NET 3.5.

Comment: Have you upgraded this project? You might have to add a reference to `System.DataSetExtension` and `System.Core`dll(should be already there). Then you need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of your file.

Comment: But i cant find system.DataSetExtension

Comment: @Happy: That's a dll that you have to add to your project. Right-click your project's references and add it. Have a look here: [How to: Create a LINQ to DataSet Project In Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552414(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Adding system.DataSetExtension dll helped. Many many many many many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're not grabbing the new table:

```
var newDt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Id");
foreach (DataRow dr in newDt.Rows) ...
```

the [`ToTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx) method doesn't modify the existing table - it creates a new one.

Comment: You are bang on :) +1 for you

Comment: But now its just returning me 1 column in the row. Its not returning me the rest of the columns :(

Comment: @Happy, that's because you're only specifying one column when you call `ToTable(true, "Id");`. You need to add more columns like this `ToTable(true, "Id", "Name", "AnotherField");` and it will be `DISTINCT` **across the entire row**.

Comment: Sorry couldnt accept your answer as my columns were dynamic and it didnt allowed me to add dynamic columns. Accepting answer from Tim Schmelter. Still many thanks to you.

Comment: `ToTable(true);` will return distinct rows for all columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning the return value to any variable, try this

```
DataTable dtnew = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Id");

foreach (DataRow row in dtnew.Rows)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(row["Id"]);
}
```